# Error on loading jsPDF in React-Native app

Tags: react-native, import, require, jspdf

I try to use jsPDF in a React-Native app but i have this error on loading.

```
Unhandled JS Exception: undefined is not an object (evaluating 't.createElementNS')
```

I try to install jsPDF like this:

```
npm install jspdf --save
```

and by specify the git commit, the lib is correctly downloaded in the node_modules directory.

I tried to import like this:

```
import * as jsPDF from 'jspdf';
```

or

```
import { default as JSPDF } from 'jspdf';
```

or

```
import jsPDF from 'jspdf';
```

or

```
var jsPDF = require('jspdf');
```

So anyone have an idea ?

Thanks.

Comment: Found any solution?

Answer (score 1):

Is it even for React Native? Something like this better?

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-pdf-lib

Comment: I saw that lib, but it's not complete, there are some features missing, so if it's possible i really want to use jsPDF.